# "IdentityServer4 + Core Identy + PostgreSql" cannot login, returning Sub Claim Missing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I setup a project as per Identity Server 4 tutorial http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html.

Combination of which has everything including API, JavaScript client, MVC Client, and Identity server as per tutorials listed.

It is using EF persisted storage rather then in memory and is using ASP Core Identity, as finally touch.

With SQL Server it works fine, however i wanted to migrate to PostgresSQL as part of self education (and frankly prefer it over sqlserver).

Everything worked up until moment when i login upon which it throws this error:

> InvalidOperationException: sub claim is missing

I've gone through all of the code but cannot figure out why this is the case.

Only change i have made is this in the Identity Server 4 startup file:

```
// CHANGE HERE: UseNpgsql instead of UseSqlServer

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresqlConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresqlConnection").ToString();

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    })
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        // CHANGE HERE: UseNpgsql instead of UseSqlServer 
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        // UseNpgsql instead of UseSqlServer
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    });
```

Everywhere i looked this seems to be the only change i need to make.

Net Core 3.1 used.

Any advice what is missing?

EDIT 1:

The issue seems to be with ASP Core Identity and PostgreSQL. Still can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see how an alternative store can cause this exception. This suggests that it's not the only change you made. The exception is rather related to [mapping](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/). Is the statement `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` present in your startup and where is it located (did you move it)?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg i didn't have this in the code, so i tried by adding it in. Still didn't work. same issue.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701348/identityserver4-core-identy-postgresql-cannot-login-returning-sub-claim-m/59715010#59715010

Comment: @PabloRecalde what about it?

Comment: Sorry wrong link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884549/identityserver4-sub-claim-is-missing?rq=1 @Aeseir

Comment: @PabloRecalde so came across that while ago, that is core 2 and id4 2 which is different to 3.0. Also he uses sql server, i am trying to use postgresql, this works on sqlserver already. His problem was due to his nginx server not having large enough buffer, mine is something fundamental within id4 setup that isn't mentioned that i need to modify.

Comment: Here is the tutorial video that might help you https://youtu.be/zNSbYggVX9k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()` .
Your final `builder` should look like

```cs
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            // CHANGE HERE: UseNpgsql instead of UseSqlServer 
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            // UseNpgsql instead of UseSqlServer
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using the same migration script for postgres?
Have you tried to delete SQL Server migration and recreate the migration script with postgres?

IdentityServer4 have a good logging, you might want to post the log result here

Comment: Yes, and yes. That is all that is outputed re Logs